# Is XSS Attack via PDF Javascript Possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, browser, xss

My question is how Javascript inside a PDF is executed in the browser?

I have encountered the following javascript code inside a PDF:

```
/Type /Action
/S /JavaScript
/JS (app.alert({cMsg: 'Hello from PDF JavaScript', cTitle: 'Testing PDF JavaScript', nIcon: 3});)
```

It seems that this code is raising an alert on the browser just like alert() would.

My question is, can It actually access the browser's data like a cookies or make a redirect like in a real XSS attack, or is there some kind of sandboxing involved?

If it's possible can you please give an example for document.cookie in a pdf.

PS: I am not referring to the Adobe API but only to PDF's opened via the browser.

Comment: It's only an XSS if you're publishing PDF files of unknown provenance.

Comment: There is no standards w.r.t. displaying a pdf in a browser, current Chrome uses a plugin, which is probably completely sandboxed, Firefox uses [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) as an extension, and loads it in a sandboxed iframe (when loaded inside a document that-is). Anyway, most browsers will probably only implement part of the [Acrobat javascript API](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) in their readers, and there, I don't think there is anything allowing stealth of data from your own doc.